# How does one set a stretched stencil image back to original scale?

Tags: image, texture-painting

I found out the hotkeys for stretching my stencil on the x axis (shift+rmb+x), now I would like to remove the scaling and put the stencil image back to its original dimensions. Strangely I haven't been able to find the quick key or the button in menu to do this, does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to go in the *N panel > Tools > Brush Settings > Texture >* Click on *Reset Transform*. It looks like scaling the way you did doesn't affect the *Size* values, which doesn't seem logical...

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a bit strange that it works that way, but, as you said, Reset Transform button does do the trick so I think I am content so long as I don't need to reset it often and search for the button again. Thank you for getting me to the right place.